Identify this batman+joker set: grey/black parts with a few golden parts

[
I found these bags, and I'd like information or instructions for the set they belong to.
There's a Batman and a Joker minifig, and some parts on mustard/golden color.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hi j montano and welcome to Bricks.SE! Please note that this is a site where human volunteers strive to provide answers to questions. Currently we can only speculate about your question, as it has not even a single sentence or question mark. You also used the bag-build tag, which adds to the confusion - did you read the tag description? It's hard to imagine why would that be applicable here. Please take the time to take the [tour] and read the [help] pages, then edit both your posts to include a question with proper tags. If something is unclear, ask here in a comment, we'll help. Play well!

For what it's worth: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=14769pb478

@IvanSanchez That could be an answer to apparently both of OP's questions.

That's not "mustard" color but rather "pearl gold", and there's a pretty unique part there:

Unique-looking parts are useful to identify sets (see How can I identify a set based on one or more original sealed bags? ), even if scanning through the printed 2x2 round tiles takes a bit of time.
That's part 14769pb478 "Tile, Round 2 x 2 with Bottom Stud Holder with Black Circles (Fuel Cap) Pattern" and it appears only in one set, 76240.

Beat me to it. We're re-building this set again, tonight.
